# program is running but i am unable to remove a constraint :(

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this program if suppose computer choose word "car" and user is entering 'c' 3 times  then answer is shown correct how to correct that?

```
import random
print("\t\t\t Welcome to 'The Advanced Jumble Game'")
print("In this program computer will choose a word and you have to guess it in 10 trails")
set=("battery","car","telephone")
choose=random.choice(set)
correct=choose
count=0
corr_length=0
print"The word contains",len(choose),"letters"
while(count<=10):
    guess=raw_input("Guess a letter\n")
    count=count+1;
    if guess in choose:
        print"Yes it's in the string"
        corr_length=corr_length+1
    else:
        print"No it's not in the string"
    if(corr_length==len(correct)):
        print("You guessed it correctly")
        break;
exit=raw_input("press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: Can you please add more description and explanation?

Comment: Create a game where the computer picks a random word and the player has to guess that word. The computer tells the player how many letters are in the word. Then the player gets five chances to ask if a letter is in the word. The computer can only respond with “yes” or “no”. Then, the player must guess the word.

Comment: You should edit the question to add your comment into the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement, you are only checking if the guessed letter is in the string, not the index of it. Therefore when you enter c three times, it actually is correct because the letter c appears in the string. Try including another counter in your while loop that increments by one when the letter is correctly guessed. Then check if the next guess is equal at the index of the counter. Not sure if this is the most efficient way to solve it but this is my solution:

```
import random
print("\t\t\t Welcome to 'The Advanced Jumble Game'")
print("In this program computer will choose a word and you have to guess it in 10 trails")
set=("battery","car","telephone")
choose=random.choice(set)
correct=choose
count=0
corr_length=0
index = 0
print"The word contains",len(choose),"letters"
while(count<=10):
    guess=raw_input("Guess a letter\n")
    count=count+1;
    print correct[index]
    if guess == correct[index]:
        print"Yes, correct letter chosen"
        corr_length=corr_length+1
        index += 1
    else:
        print"No it's not in the string"
    if(corr_length==len(correct)):
        print("You guessed it correctly")
        break;
exit=raw_input("press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: but i am unable to add index
please help :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are counting the number of times the user enters a letter in the word.

But "c" is in car each time, so:

- First time through the loop, user got one correct guess with "c"
- Second time through the loop, user has two correct guesses with "c"
- Third time through the loop, user has two correct guesses with "c"

and they win!

You never implemented the part of the problem statement in which the user actually enters their guess for what the word is.

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?  Asking for the word?  Or checking it?

Comment: checking for the word

Comment: `if word_that_user_entered == choose: print 'You guessed correctly'`